# Return list of items based on an enum value

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have a scenario below:

There are 15 enum values which will serve as parameter to my method.
Let's say enum1, enum2, enum3....enum15

I have 6 items in my list
item1, item2,....item6

Based on the enum, the method decides list of items to be returned.

I can go with the dictionary approach below:

```
Method(enum) {
dictionary = {
{enum1:[item1, item2, item3, item4, item5]},
{enum2:[item1, item2, item3, item4, item5]},
{enum3:[item2, item3, item4, item5]},
{enum4:[item2, item3, item4, item5]},
{enum5:[item2, item3, item4, item5]},
{enum6:[item2, item3, item4, item5]},
{enum7:[item2, item3, item4, item5]},
{enum8:[item2, item3, item4, item6]},
{enum9:[item1, item2, item3, item4, item6]},
{enum10:[item1]},
{enum11:[item1]},
{enum12:[item1]},
{enum13:[item1]},
{enum14:[item1]},
{enum15:[item2, item3, item4]},
}
return dictionary[enum]
}
```

I am looking for a better approach. Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You could initialize that dictionary only once instead of on every method call, if possible. Otherwise don't use a dictionary at all but return the list directly with a `switch`:

```
public List<Foo> GetFooList(MyEnum e)
{
    switch(e)
    {
        case MyEnum.enum1:
        case MyEnum.enum2:
           return new List<Foo> { new Foo("item1"), new Foo("item2"), new Foo("item3"), new Foo("item4"), new Foo("item5") };
        case MyEnum.enum3:
        case MyEnum.enum4:
        case MyEnum.enum5:
        case MyEnum.enum6:
        case MyEnum.enum7:
        case MyEnum.enum8:
            return new List<Foo> { new Foo("item2"), new Foo("item3"), new Foo("item4"), new Foo("item6") };
        case MyEnum.enum9:
        case MyEnum.enum10:
        case MyEnum.enum11:
        case MyEnum.enum12:
        case MyEnum.enum13:
        case MyEnum.enum14:
            return new List<Foo> { new Foo("item1") };
        case MyEnum.enum15:
            return new List<Foo> { new Foo("item2"), new Foo("item3"), new Foo("item4") };
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException("Enum not supported: " + e.ToString())
    }
}
```

Comment: Protip: use [`ExhaustiveMatching`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExhaustiveMatching.Analyzer) to get compile-time errors if your `switch` is non-exhaustive over its enum type.

Comment: Can also use the [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) which is pretty neat